Change horizontal snap scroll to vertical snap scroll for mobile
How to change horizontal snap scroll to vertical snap scroll for mobile?
This sample (by GSAP) keeps horizontal scrolling in mobile, but I want to change it to snap vertical scrolling in mobile, while keep horizontal for desktop.
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".panel");

gsap.to(sections, {
  xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
  ease: "none",
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".container",
    pin: true,
    scrub: 1,
    snap: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
    // base vertical scrolling on how wide the container is so it feels more natural.
    end: "+=3500",
  }
});

All samples I've founded are keeping horizontal scrolling in mobile, but I want to keep horizontal scrolling for desktop and change it to vertical in mobile with snap for both.
Is it possible?
Samples I could find:
[https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/YzygYvM][1]
[https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/NWxqaOL][2]

